# How can Kotlin's Set be covariant when contains() takes E?

Tags: kotlin, collections, covariance

I was looking into co- and contravariance in several programming languages' collection libraries, and stumbled over Kotlin's [Set](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html) interface.

It is documented as

```
interface Set<out E> : Collection<E>
```

which means it is covariant – only "producing" E objects, [following the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance), not consuming them.

And `Set<String>` becomes a subtype of `Set<Any>`.

Yet, it has those two methods:

```
abstract fun contains(element: E): Boolean
abstract fun containsAll(elements: Collection<E>): Boolean
```

So when I create a class implementing `Set<String>`, I have to implement (beside others) `contains(String)`. But later someone can use my class as a `Set<Any>` and call `set.contains(5)`.

I actually tried this:

```
class StringSet : Set<String> {
    override val size = 2
    override fun contains(element: String): Boolean {
        println("--- StringSet.contains($element)")
        return element == "Hallo" || element == "World"
    }

    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<String>) : Boolean =
        elements.all({it -> contains(it)})
    override fun isEmpty() = false
    override fun iterator() = listOf("Hallo", "World").iterator()

}

fun main() {
    val sset : Set<String> = StringSet()
    println(sset.contains("Hallo"))
    println(sset.contains("xxx"))
    //// compiler error:
    // println(set.contains(5))

    val aset : Set<Any> = sset
    println(aset.contains("Hallo"))
    println(aset.contains("xxx"))
    // this compiles (and returns false), but the method is not actually called
    println(aset.contains(5)) 
}
```

([Run online](https://pl.kotl.in/uAKB2qUHH))

So it turns out that `Set<String>` is not a "real" subtype of `Set<Any>`, as the `set.contains(5)` works with the second but not the first.

Actually calling the contains method even works at runtime – just my implementation will never be called, and it just prints `false`.

Looking into the source code of the interface, it turns out that the two methods are actually declared as

```
abstract fun contains(element: @UnsafeVariance E): Boolean
abstract fun containsAll(elements: Collection<@UnsafeVariance E>): Boolean
```

What is going on here?
Is there some special compiler magic for Set?
Why is this not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 9):

Declaration-site covariance in the form of the `out` modifier misses a useful use case of making sure that an instance passed as an argument is generally sensible to pass here. The `contains` functions are a good example.

In the particular case of `Set.contains`, the `@UnsafeVariance` annotation is used to ensure that the function accepts an instance of `E`, as passing an `element` that is not `E` into `contains` makes no sense – all proper implementation of `Set` will always return `false`. The implementations of `Set` are not supposed to store the `element` passed to `contains` and thus should never return it from any other function with the return type `E`. So a properly implemented `Set` won't violate the variance restrictions at runtime.

The `@UnsafeVariance` annotation actually suppresses the compiler variance conflicts, like using an `out`-projected type parameter in an `in`-position.

Its motiviation is best described in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out/):

> #### `@UnsafeVariance` annotation
>
> Sometimes we need to suppress declaration-site variance checks in our classes. For example, to make `Set.contains` typesafe while keeping read-only sets co-variant, we had to do it:
>
> ```
> interface Set<out E> : Collection<E> {
>      fun contains(element: @UnsafeVariance E): Boolean
> }
> ```
>
> This puts some responsibility on the implementor of `contains`, because with this check suppressed the actual type of element may be anything at all at runtime, but it’s sometimes necessary to achieve convenient signatures. See more on the type-safety of collections below.
>
> So, we introduced the `@UnsafeVariance` annotation on types for this purpose. It’s been deliberately made long and stands out to warn agains abusing it.

<sup>The rest of the blog post also explicitly mentions that the signature of `contains` using `@UnsafeVariance` improves type-safety.</sup>

The alternative to introducing `@UnsafeVariance` was to keep `contains` accepting `Any`, but this option lacks the type check on `contains` calls that would detect erroneous calls with `element`s that can't be present in the set due to not being instances of `E`.

Comment: But how comes that my implementation doesn't even get called with this argument?

Comment: Also, I like how the "responsibility on the implementor of contains" is not even mentioned in the documentation of contains.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes this seems to involve some compiler magic. If you check the bytecode generated for your `StringSet` implementation, you will find that the bridge method `contains(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z` checks the `element` for being a `String` and immediately returns false without calling the overridden implementation if it's not. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/711ad7d972822b414e35cdd36dfcc222).

Comment: So I guess the point about `some responsibility on the implementor of contains` is now handled by the compiler for the built-in collection interfaces. However, I guess it's not handled for custom types with `@UnsafeVariance` in the signatures. Let me check.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler just insert a `CHECKAST` instruction in the bridge, and it throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime if a bad object is passed. See [another gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/8978a0abadb29a4ea1c544fbd95ea6ef).

Comment: In case of `containsAll` the responsibility to work accurately with the argument is still on the implementor, because in this case the bridge cannot check the actual type of the erased collection argument.