# Why is the key type parameter of a Kotlin Map invariant?

Tags: kotlin, generics, collections, covariance

The `Map` interface in Kotlin (using V1.6.21) has a signature of

```kotlin
interface Map<K, out V>
```

Why is `K` invariant instead of covariant (`out K`)?

The documentation of type parameter `K` says:

The map is invariant in its key type, as it can accept key as a parameter (of containsKey for example) and return it in keys set.

However, interface `Set` is covariant in the element type, so the the last part ("return it in keys set") is not applicable, at least not immediately.

Further, the type parameter `K` is used only at occurrences where the map state is not modified, for lookup purposes (methods `containsKey`, `get`, `getOrDefault`). At these places, isn't it safe to use `@UnsafeVariance`? After all, that same technique was employed to `Map`'s value type parameter `V`, for example in `containsValue`, to allow making `V` covariant.

Comment: I think your point about the `Set` interface should rather be about `Set.contains` which uses `@UnsafeVariance` while `Map.containsKey` doesn't.

Comment: I actually I'm more surprised about `Set` being covariant in its element type, because using `@UnsafeVariance` should only be done when we know the implementation is safe. In particular for `Set.contains(K)`, we need to know it wouldn't break if an instance of a supertype of `K` is given as argument. Some implementations of `Set` might not be safe in this respect, so it's weird that the annotation is used on the interface, but I guess that brings a lot of convenience at little cost to safety.

Comment: @Joffrey What implementations of `Set` "might not be safe in this respect"?

Comment: `class MyUnsafeSet : Set<String>` which prints a property of string in its `contains(String)` implementation? If you pass a `Any()` to its contains method, it would break when trying to call `String`-specific things on it

Comment: @Sweeper In Java, there is `Set.contains(Object)`, but in Kotlin it's defined as `Set.contains(E)` - so the implementer should be able to rely on the object being an instance of `E` or subtypes, but not supertypes of it.

Comment: @Joffrey Ah, I made the incorrect assumption that all set implementations would be generic and be able to store any given type. [This bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43257/UnsafeVariance-types-in-parameters-are-not-type-safe-unless-erased-to-their-upper-bounds) I found earlier seems relevant to what you are saying, though I don't think it is much to do with what OP is asking.

Comment: It seems that the compiler treats `Set` in a special way and adds some safety guards to the implementations of `containsKey` in sets that have a narrower upper bound than `Any`, see the comments on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262636/2196460

Comment: @Sweeper it has to do with the OP's question, because the justification for `Map` being invariant in `K` because of `containsKey` should exactly apply to `Set.contains` as well

Comment: @hotkey yeah I just experimented and it turns out the compiler actually generates `contains(Object)` bridge methods that return `false` on things that are not `K` and only call my implementation on `K` instances. But that's definitely cheating as far as `@UnsafeVariance` is concerned. It only works because of this trick

Comment: By the way it actually fails for `containsAll` - no safety net here due to erasure of the collection passed to it: https://pl.kotl.in/pu9CsntbJ

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that using a `Map<KSubtype, V>` as a `Map<KSupertype, V>` (where `KSubtype : KSupertype`) does not really make a lot of sense because the former, by construction, cannot contain entries with keys other than `KSubtype`.

So a proper implementation should return `null` from all calls to `get(kSupertype)` as well as return `false` from those to `containsKey(kSupertype)`.

In the case of `Set<out E>` it's only the `contains` function that needs unsafe variance, and `Map` would also require unsafe variance on `get`. This might have been too much of a peculiarity to support, compared to the value of supporting the use case.

Comment: Not sure why they couldn't generate bridge method returning `null` for `Map.get` like they did to return `false` for `Set.contains`, though. It probably makes little sense, to be fair.